# Connecting ubuntu computers via ssh

Tags: 12.04, networking, ssh

I am trying to connect the computers on my home wifi network via SSH. But I get "connection refused". Here is a supporting image (ip address changed for security purposes). [image]

Why is it refusing the connection? The username and password for the other machine are the admin account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other note you should really take .. change the port 22, we get drive by,s that try and log in to port 22, some other people will do a full port scan to find your ssh port, but by changing the port it knocks a few hackers straight out. you can do this in..

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Also after you get the key working turn off PermitRootlogin no.

Answer (score 2):

The SSH server is not installed by default.

Make sure that is installed first

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If it still doesn't work check the following:

1. Can you ping the computer you're connecting to?
2. Are there any IPTables rules loaded?  (sudo iptables -L)
3. There may be an option on the wifi router to prevent clients from seeing each other. Called wireless client isolation.  Turn it off if enabled.

Comment: hi @matt H well, i am able to ping the computer no problem.  here is the output from the iptables command: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination As for the router having wireless client isolation, I dont know. How do I check that?

Comment: By pinging it.  Sounds like that's not the problem.  Did you check that openssh-server is installed?